# Trying to insert using Slick with the newly generated ID from the db

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

```
def insert(u: User): Future[User] = {
  val insertQuery = users returning users.map(_.id) into ((user, id) => user.copy(id = id))
  val action = insertQuery += u
  db.run(action)
}

case class User(id: Int, name: String, ..)
```

When I call this method with a user like:

```
User(0, "john", ..)
```

I get the error:

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key
>   value violates unique constraint "users_pmkey"

It seems to be trying to insert the 0 as the PK.  In my DAO I set the column with:

```
def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
```

I am basically trying to do 2 things:

1. insert the User
2. return the User with the newly generated ID by postgresql.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If your ID is generated by postgresql, you can use `O.AutoInc`:

```
def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
```

In your case class, use Option for your `id` field:

```
case class User(id: Option[Int], name: String, ..)
```

and create your new User like this:

```
User(None, "john", ..)
```